# How can I apply jQuery.click to first level items only?

Tags: jquery

I need to apply a jQuery.click to the first level items only. How do I do that?

Here is my list:

```
<ul id="adminMenu">
  <li id="A">
    <h3><a href="">Item 1</a></h3>
  </li>
  <li id="B">
    <h3>Item 2</h3>
    <ul style="display: block;">
      <li id="a1"> Sub Item 1 </li>
      <li id="a2"> Sub Item 2 </li>
      <li id="a3"> Sub Item 3 </li>
    </ul>
  </li> 
  <li id="C">
    <h3>Item 3</h3>
    <ul style="display: none;">
      <li> Sub Item 4 </li>
      <li> Sub Item 5 </li>
    </ul>
  </li> 
</ul>
```

And here is the jQuery

```
jQuery('#adminMenu > li').click(function(){
  alert('test');
});
```

**UPDATE**
The Alert should **not** fire when I click a Sub Menu item, only when I click list item A, B or C.

**SOLUTION 1** 
This is working code based on Marcels suggestion.

```
  jQuery('#adminMenu > li > h3').click(function(e) {
    var activeUL = jQuery("#adminMenu > li ul:visible");
    var activeLI = jQuery("#adminMenu > li ul:visible").parent('li:first');
    var clicked = jQuery(this).parent('li:first');
    // Close submenu
    activeUL.hide('fast');
    // Open submenu
    if( activeLI.attr('id') != clicked.attr('id') )        
      clicked.children('ul').show('fast');
  });
```

**SOLUTION 2** 
This is working code based on Eyelids suggestion.

```
  jQuery('#adminMenu > li').click(function(e) {
      var clicked = jQuery(e.target);
      // Ensure we're checking which list item is clicked,
      // other children should be allowed
      if(!clicked.is('li') && clicked.parents('li').length > 0) {
          // :first ensures we do not select higher level list items
          clicked = clicked.parents('li:first');
      }
      // If clicked list item is a child of another list item, we'll exit here
      if(!clicked.is('#adminMenu > li')) {
          return;
      }
    var activeUL = jQuery("#adminMenu > li ul:visible");
    var activeLI = jQuery("#adminMenu > li ul:visible").parent('li:first');

    // Close submenu
    activeUL.hide('fast');
    // Open submenu
    if( activeLI.attr('id') != clicked.attr('id') )        
      clicked.children('ul').show('fast');
  });
```

Thanks guys! I would never have managed this without your help! :)

Comment: Regarding update 2: yes, which is why you'll need to detect if the sub-items were clicked. Click events "bubble", meaning that a click event on a child element is also a click event on its parent elements. The simplest cross-browser* way to stop this bubbling and isolate clicks on parents is to determine if a child element triggered the click event and exit in that case. See my updated answer for implementation of that method. * Note: Non-IE browsers allow "capturing" events (rather than "bubbling"), but since this isn't supported in IE, it's not worth relying on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
jQuery('#adminMenu > li').click(function(e) {
    var clicked = jQuery(e.target);
    // Ensure we're checking which list item is clicked,
    // other children should be allowed
    if(!clicked.is('li') && clicked.parents('li').length > 0) {
        // :first ensures we do not select higher level list items
        clicked = clicked.parents('li:first');
    }
    // If clicked list item is a child of another list item, we'll exit here
    if(!clicked.is('#adminMenu > li')) {
        return;
    }
    alert('test');
});
```

Updated to exit if clicked list item is not an immediate descendant of `#adminMenu`.

Comment: The above code, will also fire the alert when i click a sub item.

Comment: If the code you have is still not working how you want, can you clarify the question? Do you want the event handler to ignore clicks on child list items?

Comment: Thanks eyelidlessness. I'm using your solution considering your comment to Marcel.

Comment: My activeUL and activeLI restricts this to only 1 level. Is there a more general way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is, that you add the click to the whole LI (which includes all childs etc). You have to "clickify" the labels only, so use:

```
jQuery("#adminMenu > li > h3").click(...);
```

Comment: It's the first one. But it gets applied to my sub elements. So clicking Sub Item 1 also fires the Alert.

Comment: Yea, took me some time to grasp the issue ;) Try the new one.

Comment: MikeWyatt, it's only less code assuming that the structure used is the only way it'll ever be used. Add any other child elements or even child text nodes to the top-level list items, and you'll get undesired behavior.

Comment: And I want to emphasize that there is no way to ensure that text nodes which are immediate children of the top-level list items are clickable with only a selector in jQuery. Much as I'd like jQuery/Sizzle to allow selecting non-element nodes, it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks Marcel. I got a working solution now with your example. No I'll dive into Eyelids suggestion, as it is a slightly better solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Get a set of elements containing all of the unique immediate children of each of the matched set of elements.

children( [expr] )

http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/children

```
   jQuery('#adminMenu').children('li').children('h3').click(function()
   {  
       alert('test');
   });
```

Comment: Nope. That will also fire the Alert when i click Sub Item 1.

Comment: Edited after clarification of question (I might have been a bad reader :)

Comment: The difference is that ("#adminMenu > li > h3") should match "all sub elements, not just immediate children, so you should have no clicks on "h3" get fired on sub elements of "h3' if I did this right. (making assumption you "might" have an "h3" inside the inner li as well)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.adminMenu>li').not(":has(ul)").on('click',function(e){
    alert('test');
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: This is the easiest way to apply jQuery.click to the first level items only in a ul list.

Answer (score -1):

```
jQuery('#adminMenu li:first').
```

Comment: If I'm not wrong, that will only apply the .click to the first li item. I need to apply it to ALL first level li items.

Comment: -1 This will select the first matching li element.  That is not the same as selecting all the first-level li elements.

Comment: @PragneshChauhan. You clearly didn't read the question! this does answer the question! (but it's wrong) it should not be deleted unless the Sergey will decide to do so.