# Execute a specific action only for first level li elements in a ul?

Tags: jquery

```js
jQuery('ul.nav.lvl1>li').on("click", function() {
  alert('hello');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav lvl1">
  <li><a href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

We are have problem because this action use for all `li` in all `ul` but we would like use action only for `li` first level in `ul`.

How to solve a problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568235/how-can-i-apply-jquery-click-to-first-level-items-only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than stopping event propagation (which could affect and suppress all other event listeners that are attached), you can simply check whether the closest ancestor `li` element is the element that the event listener is attached to.

In the example below, `event.target` refers to the element that was clicked, while `event.currentTarget` refers to the element that the event listener is attached to.

By using the `.closest()` method, you can determine whether `event.target` is the element that the event listener was originally attached to:

```js
$('ul.nav.lvl1 > li').on('click', function(event) {
  if ($(event.target).closest('li').is(event.currentTarget)) {
    alert('Clicked');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav lvl1">
  <li><a href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use **[stop propagation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)** for the inner `li` elements. Otherwise the clicks on the inner elements are propagated to the parent elements.

```js
jQuery('ul.nav.lvl1>li').on("click",function(){
   alert('hello');
});

jQuery('ul.nav.lvl1 > li li').on("click",function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav lvl1">
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think `.stopPropagation()` should be avoided (as I mentioned in my answer), just in case there are any other events attached to those elements.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the selector you use...

when you use a selector such as `ul>li`, you will target only the li that are direct children of the ul, so it won't fire on the li that are children of your li.